# How to get rid of a "non-breaking space" inside a Swift string?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I retrieved some strings from `AddressBook.framework`'s `ABRecordCopyValue` method by casting the returned value of `takeRetainedValue()` as a `String` object.

```
let unmanagedFirstNameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)
if unmanagedFirstNameProperty != nil {
    contactFirstName = unmanagedFirstNameProperty!.takeRetainedValue() as? String
}

let formattedName:String = contactFirstName.replaceOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(formattedName)
```

I want to get rid of the spaces inside this `String` object by calling `replaceOccurrences(of:with:)` method, but that doesn't work (the spaces are still there after I call this method) and I was told by the Apple Framework Reference that this is usually because of the string encoding, containing "non-break spaces" which I've heard a lot about, but I have no idea how to make a "non-break space" into a normal space. Is this even possible? If so, what would be the best approach to make the characters inside a `String` compatible with the `replaceOccurrences(of:with:)` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, where you have `contactFirstName.replaceOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")` make sure that within the quotes, **the space character should be typed in with the option key held down.  If you type a space with the option key held down, you should get a non-breaking space.**

Then you can replace it with a normal space, or an empty string if you wish.

Alternatively, as suggested in comments, the following may be more readable:

`contactFirstName.replaceOccurrences(of: "\u{00A0}", with: "")`

That way it doesn't look like a normal space in code.

Comment: THANKS! It worked! I wasn't expecting the solution to be something as simple as this, to be honest :)

Comment: It's better to use `"\u{00A0}"`, so it doesn't just look like a regular space