# Word Wrap Occurs Inconsistently in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a UILabel that is designed to expand in height when the width of the text's CGSize is greater than the width of the label. I accomplish that with this code:

```
func viewHeight(_ locationName: String) -> CGFloat {

    let locationName = tappedLocation[0].name

    var size = CGSize()

    if let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", size: 17.0) {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]
        size = (locationName as NSString).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
    }

    let normalCellHeight = horizontalStackViewHeightConstraint.constant
    let extraLargeCellHeight = horizontalStackViewHeightConstraint.constant + 20.33

    let textWidth = ceil(size.width)
    let cellWidth = ceil(nameLabel.frame.width)

    if textWidth > cellWidth {
        return extraLargeCellHeight
    } else {
        return normalCellHeight
    }
}
```

Lines = 0 and line break style = Word Wrap:

[image]

The label lives inside a vertical stackView, and is constrained to its top, leading and trailing edges and a stackView beneath it. The height of the label and the UIView properly expand in height when the CGSize width of the text is longer than the width of the label. All well and good.

However, the words do not wrap consistently. This behavior is intentional:

Bobby Mao's Chinese Kitchen & Bar:
XL cell. Width: 184.0,
Text width: 287.0

[image]

This behavior is not (why isn't "steak" on the prior line?):

Ruth's Chris Steak House:
XL cell. Width: 184.0,
Text width: 204.0

[image]

And neither is this (why didn't Gina wrap if it's over the label width parameter?):

Ristorante Mamma Gina:
XL cell. Width: 184.0,
Text width: 191.0

[image]

I have also set a temporary background color on my label to ensure that it does, in fact correspond to the intended width. The label in this example creates another line when the label's width is exceeded, but the text does not wrap:

[image]

I have read the other entries on Stack Overflow about word wrapping. I don't believe this is a duplicate. I do not have trouble creating two lines for my text. I don't have trouble with word wrapping occurring. I have trouble with *how* and *when* it is occurring.

I think the intent is clear... what am I missing?

Comment: Give your label a temporary background color to make sure the label's width is what you think it is. Also make sure the string doesn't have a non-breaking space in it.

Comment: Ok. My label width is a determined via a print statement of label.width... could that be wrong somehow?

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my answer to show that the background color corresponds with the intended width (and adjusting the height to create another line when over the width of the label). I also tried removing non-breaking spaces by using the example shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40498845/7134142. But no avail! Do you have any other suggestions? I think you've helped me in the past actually... thanks for that.